# Sql like pulling different amount of results

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-like

Im trying to work out some groups which will take any word like what im looking for and eventually group them together, however when I use the like in the where statement one way I get more results than when I use it the other way and I just wondered why?

If I use this is the where statement I get more results as its pulling out anything like the word ive listed including ones that have whitespace before/after

```
and name like '%offer1%'
or name like '%offer2%' 
or name like '%offer3%' 
or name like '%offer4%' -- 244
```

However when I search each word separate I get less values as its not getting the words where there may e white space after and I just wondered why really? For the below code I just ran each of these individually rather than all together like shows as I had commented them out each time to get the counts which are at the end of the row

```
and name like '%offer1%' -- 97
and name like '%offer2%' -- 38
and name like '%offer3%' -- 2
and name like '%offer4%' -- 6 (143)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Of course AND and OR will extract different rows and numbers of rows? In one all conditions must be true, in the other just one of them needs to be.

Comment: I didn't run all the AND statements at once, I mentioned I commented them out and ran each one separate in the second query just to find the count for each option and to find out what was missing. I would have though a like '%offer1%' would still get the same number of offers as the first query but it dosent as it is missing ones with whitespace where as when they are grouped together in the first query it dosent miss ones with white space? Does that make sense?

Comment: Unfortunately, you aren't showing us the statements that you ran; you're only showing a small part. Because of that, we can't be sure why you get those results. Most likely, it's because of how your clauses interact with whatever the rest of your statements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `WHERE` statement, which is not shown here.

```
where <condition>
and name like '%offer1%'
or name like '%offer2%' 
or name like '%offer3%' 
or name like '%offer4%'
```

This is interpreted as :

```
where (<condition> and name like '%offer1%') 
or (name like '%offer2%')
or (name like '%offer3%')
or (name like '%offer4%')
```

Which is not the same as what you originally wanted to achieve.

You should change your query using parenthesis :

```
and (name like '%offer1%'
or name like '%offer2%' 
or name like '%offer3%' 
or name like '%offer4%')
```

Comment: Ah that's the one its the brackets I needed, will play around with where I put them to make sure I get the data im after Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of AND / OR logic. Learn more about it from here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

If you use "and" conditions, all the conditions must be true for a record to show in results (therefore your code gives you results where name is like offer1 AND at the same time like offer2 and at the same time offer3 and at the same time offer4).

If you use "or" conditions, any of the conditions must be true (therefore it gives you results where name is like offer2 or instead the name is like offer3 etc.).

If you were to combine AND / OR logic, AND is run first, then OR (just as order of operation  in math.. first multiplication/division, then addition/substraction).

`WHERE (A and B) OR (C) OR (D)`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I understand the and or logic, I just don't understand why one like statement gets more results than another as its picking out white space where as the other isn't, I didn't run all the and statements at once I just ran them individually to get the count for each to see how many there were different.

Comment: Did you use any other conditions besides those you mentioned? Even when you run them individually (given that you also have other conditions), if you use AND (and only have AND conditions in where clause), all conditions must be true at the same time. If you use OR (In the end of AND conditions), it will give you more results because all conditions for every row don't have to be true at the same time.

Comment: Any other conditions used were consistant between both queries and have no affect of the counts. All I want to know is why the first bit of code gets anything with the word I want incuding words with whitespace before or after it, where as just the AND statement dosent look to be doing that, I though a % is meant to get any character before or after the word im looking for?